# How to get selected row data as javascript jsonObject from Datatables using Tabletools

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, tabletools, jquery-datatables-editor

I want to make an editable table from [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/).

I want to develop the same functionality as provided by the [Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) which is not open source.

The user should be able to select a row from the table and then click on an edit button to modify the contents of the row displayed by a bootstrap modal. 
Then on clicking on the update button in the modal, the modified row data should be sent to the server.

For implementing this, I read about the plug-in Buttons of the TableTools. But I don't know how to get the data from the tabletools as key value pairs in javascript.

I have found [this](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/plug-in.html), but it displays whole table data as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have used my own code and shared it [here](http://marothiatechs.blogspot.in/2015/05/creating-your-own-datatables-editor.html) .